# How to show slider in WP header and run?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

**/img/slides/1.jpg" alt="" />**

I use above the code in WP slider. But do not show slider in wp website. How can I solve this ? Please suggest me from expertise in WP theme developer .

Comment: Really need more information on this, are you using wp_header in your theme? Are there any console errors or errors in your log?

Comment: You are using any plugin for the slider

Comment: @Rezaul Karim, where is the code?